# I'm getting invalid taxonomy in init action

Tags: functions, taxonomy, errors

As described [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29150/why-is-my-working-custom-taxonomy-not-in-get-taxonomies-array) (and many more similar questions), You can't use taxonomy functions before `init` action

The thing is that i'm trying this:

```
add_action('init', 'save_job_candidate_still');
function save_job_candidate_still () {
    $candidate_area = $_REQUEST['area_id']; // <-- 270
    if (is_numeric($candidate_area)) {
        $candidate_area = (int) $candidate_area;
        $candidate_area_text = get_term_link($candidate_area, 'area-trabajo');
        var_dump($candidate_area_text); // <- here
    }
    // more irrelevant code..
}
```

The `var_dump` logs:

```
object(WP_Error)#2495 (2) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["invalid_taxonomy"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(20) "Taxonomia no vÃ¡lida"
    }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

But I don't understand, I checked:
* The taxonomy exists
* function called after `init` action

Anyone knows why could be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure your taxonomy name is `area-trabajo`?

Comment: Yes ( i added it to the question ), in fact; tried to change the action to `template_redirect` and it works..

Comment: have you tried changing the priority? Hooked functions run in order, you can't run something earlier if it depends on something that runs later in the same action.